# Google play console publishing diferent apk then I uploaded

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, google-play-console

Few weeks back I uploaded first version of my app to google play. Everything, including updates, worked great until now.

When I install apk directly to my phone everything works as expected I have 0 High score, google achievements works and ad is showing.

But when I dowload the SAME apk from google play(after I published it) the game shows highscore of 60 and neither achievements or ad are showing. (I am using Unity and its playerPrefs system of saving data).

I went and investigate the situation and I found out something weird to me.
In the artefact library I downloaded my apk and there are 2 types.

1) The one that I uploaded

2)One tha google somehow edited

Somehow the 2. apk diferes A LOT from what I uploaded.. Namely the uploaded state of highscore(even some other saved stuf)
It is possible that I forget to clear playerPrefs in earlier version, but NOT in this one.
**How is it posible that google somehow merges my new apk with older one?**
And when I am uploading new apk I dont keep the old ones, I am deactivating them so where is the problem.. It is my first published app and I dont know some of the "advanced wording".So please if you know what is happening go slow on me ;)

(Sure I missed something :/ )

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't modify APKs uploaded to the Play Console. The fact that you observe a different behaviour of your app related to gaming suggests that maybe your integration with the game library has some issues.

Overall, given that we don't know the setup of your console and your releases, you would have more luck reaching out to the Play Console support team.